# How to properly use Observables with nestjs?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Im working on a API that can hanlde users (just that for simplicity) doing basic crud operations.
I got the user service something like:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class UsersService {
        constructor(
            @InjectRepository(User)
            private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
        ) { }
...
        async findById(id: number): Promise<User> {
            return this.usersRepository.findOne(id);
    }
```

and a controller:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@UseFilters(QueryFailedExceptionFilter)
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {

    constructor(private readonly _userService: UsersService) { }

 @Get(':id')
    findById(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Observable<User> {
        return from(this._userService.findById(id));
    }
```

And that works, i can find , create, delete, etc.. the problem is that if i try to finOne user  ( Get(:id) from my controller ) and if it not exist, it just return a 200 ok with no response to the client , but it should be a 404 because the resource is not found.

Reading the documentation i understand (hope i did it right) that we can return a observable and it will be automatically subcribed. So the question is , where and how to hanlde if the result for findOne is nothing and return a response with the appropiate status, using observables of course.

I have try to find some examples , but i only find a few examples working with promises and most of the time they just ignore the not find user case.

PD: "They" said that i should hanlde that in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a 404 and use observables, what you can do is something like this:

```js
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@UseFilters(QueryFailedExceptionFilter)
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {

    constructor(private readonly _userService: UsersService) { }

 @Get(':id')
    findById(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Observable<User> {
        return from(this._userService.findById(id)).pipe(
          map(user => {
            if (!user) {
              throw new NotFoundException();
            }
            return user;
          })
        );
    }
```

I'm personally a fan of keeping all of my logic in services instead of controllers, keeps the controllers thin and the logic re-usable for the most part.

Comment: Thats quick, thanks. Ok it works , i think i have to get deep with operators. The only thing is that the response status is always 400 for exceptions. I know i can use @Res() to set the status, but i don't like it at all and want to avoid specific library approach. By the way i'm agree with you about 'keeping all of my logic in services' but for example if i use a base class to handle basic operations like find,delete,update for all services and also want to send custom messages on response i think that doing that on controllers could be right in that case.

Comment: I think i can handle the exceptions with a global exception filter and change the status code there... just no sure if it is the best approach.

Comment: I'm getting a proper 404 back when I try on a local machine using the `NotFoundException`

Comment: Yep, you are right. I was catching all the errors with the filter and setting response to 400 (i change to the specific exception i want to handle with that, and now it works), my mistake. Thanks a lot.